# Создание подключения к базе данных в PHP из файла

Tags: php, mysql, файлы

Интересно мнение по созданию подключения к базе данных.

Суть в следующем: создаю класс базы данных и хочу добавить универсальности, то есть в конструкторе инициализировать переменные необходимые для подключения. Для этого их нужно указывать в параметрах создания класса.
Появилась идея передать туда имя файла и считывать уже от туда данные (это вроде как безопасней получиться, тк доступ к файлу потом закрою).

ВОПРОС: сильно это будет тормозить при частых запросах, так вообще делается или я велосипед изобретаю, а также это реально обезопасит создание базы от некорректного ввода?

Comment: "обезопасит создание базы от некорректного ввода" - какого, например?

Comment: Хммм, а точно ведь, что там сломать-то можно при коннекте. Но использовать файл - это нормально или нет?

Comment: Нормально. [Пример](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database). Не хардкодить же, а потом искать по всем исходникам.